# Page numbering disappear when using together (1) fancyhdr and (2) geometry packages

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, geometry, reledmac, reledpar

**[ORIGINAL QUESTION: How to insert the page numbering with reledmac and reledpar?]**

I am writing a book in two languages, with facing pages, by using several packages, as the [matrita package](https://github.com/franen/matrita), the `reledmac` and `reledpar` packages, the `fancyhdr` and `geometry` packages, etc., and I need to add the **page numbers at the bottom of each page**.

If I use this **MWE without my additional packages, everything works** and I can see the page numbers (at the top of each page):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\numberlinefalse  
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Instead, if I use my additional packages, the page numbers are not there anymore - Please see this **MWE with my additional packages, that does not work (i.e. I do not see pages numbers)**:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\numberlinefalse  
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[paperwidth=120mm,paperheight=210mm,top=12mm,bottom=6mm,outer=20mm,inner=13mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{matrita}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\respfont}{\bfseries}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\definecolor{respcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{etgray}{gray}{0.8}
\setlength{\afterpoemtitleskip}{2ex plus 0ex minus 1ex}
\setlength{\beforepoemtitleskip}{2.5ex plus 1ex minus 2ex}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}
\setlength{\titleindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\definecolor{crosscolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\renewcommand{\intestfont}[1]{{\Large\scshape\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\nomelibrofont}[1]{{\bfseries#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewCoffin\InitialCoffin
\NewCoffin\RestCoffin
\NewCoffin\LineCoffin
\newlength{\InitKernCorr}
\tl_new:N \Part_Title_tl
\tl_new:N \Rest_of_Title_tl
\tl_set:Nn \First_Title_tl {\tl_head:N \Part_Title_tl}
\tl_set:Nn \Rest_of_Title_tl {\tl_tail:N \Part_Title_tl}
\RenewDocumentCommand {\momento}{O{0em}m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \Part_Title_tl {#2}
  \setlength{\InitKernCorr}{#1}
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\InitialCoffin{
    \normalfont\scalebox{2}{\Large\textcolor{red}{\First_Title_tl}\hspace{\InitKernCorr}}
  }
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\RestCoffin{
    \normalfont\Large\textcolor{red}{\MakeTextUppercase \Rest_of_Title_tl}
  }
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\LineCoffin{
    \textcolor{black}{\rule[-1.5pt]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\CoffinWidth\InitialCoffin\relax}{0.6pt}}
  }
  \JoinCoffins\LineCoffin[l,t]\RestCoffin[l,b]
  \JoinCoffins\LineCoffin[l,b]\InitialCoffin[r,b]
  \par\vspace*{5\baselineskip}\noindent\TypesetCoffin\LineCoffin (0mm, 0mm)\vspace{3\baselineskip}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\sottomomento}[1]{{\intestfont{#1}}\par\medskip}





\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: To clarify: (1) With your MWE, I *do* get a page number in the outer header of the page (=top right or top left); numbers are lowercase "i ii iii" (since you selected `roman`; `Roman` would be "I II III"). Do you get that too? But you would like to have it in the footer, right? (2) This isn't at all related to `reledmac`, which generally doesn't affect the page numbering; it's only about the `book` class.

Comment: Thanks @marquinho for your reply! After using ```\pagenumbering``` I tried not to use it anymore and I tried to just use what ```reledmac``` and ```reledpar``` provide..... Then I found out that the code, as shown in **MWE without my additional packages**, works, i.e. it shows the page numbering, while when I tried to add my additional packages, as shown in the **MWE with my additional packages**, the page numbers disappear.....

Comment: Sorry for changing a bit my question (Yes, initially I just mentioned that I used ```\pagenumbering{roman}```)... but I then realised that I did not put complete/full MWEs that people could copy and paste in their machines.... To reply to your question (1), if I use the **MWE with my additional packages** together with ```\pagenumbering{roman}```, I do not see any page number yet....Instead if I use **MWE without my additional packages**, both with or without the command```\pagenumbering{roman}```, I do see page numbers at the top of each page.......About your question (2), Yes, in the footer

Comment: Great, now I see the problem (and luckily there's an answer). This question is definitely not about `reledmac` and `reledpar` though, so I suggest you edit the question to remove those tags and maybe change the title (maybe mention `fancyhdr` and/or `geometry` but definitely not `reledmac`) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.... Well, actually the question is still related to ```reledmac``` and/or ```reledpar``` since they provide (but I do not know which of them exactly) page numbering by default - Right ?? Please correct if I am wrong - Indeed, my **MWE without my additional packages** gives me page numbering without any additional command as ```\pagenumbering{roman}```..... Title and description slightly changed :) Many thanks !!

Comment: (Sorry I'm splitting hairs – however:) "since they provide page numbering by default": you may be thinking of *line* numbers? All the LaTeX standard classes provide page numbers by default. – And try to see it this way: if you remove `reledmac/par` and all the attendant definitions from your document, and write f.i. `\begin{document} \lipsum\lipsum \end{document}`, the page layout does change somewhat, but you get the same problems: page number is not typeset (bc of `\fancyfoot{}`) and footer is too low on the page (bc of `bottom`). Hence, the issues are *independent* of `reledmac/par`.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot :) I changed the title again ... Hope it is better now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification and the example.

The two roots of the problem are the following:

(1) You have given the instruction `\fancyfoot{}` on l. 30. This *"clears all footer fields"*, as you remark in your code, and eliminates the page number, which otherwise would be shown at the bottom (as per default).
Comment/delete this line and the page number will be typeset by LaTeX.

(2) Your bottom margin, as specified in `geometry` (`bottom=6mm`), is very tight. Thus, the page number, *even when* typeset, *flows off of the page margin*.
You need a larger value of `bottom`, and I recommend experimenting with that value as well as with the option `foot=0mm` (which minimizes the vertical space between text area and footer).

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to shrink this space even more. And of course, a larger bottom margin eats away at your total text height. So you'll have to experiment and find out what works for you.

The following values add up to a rather pleasant layout, I think:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=120mm,paperheight=210mm,top=12mm,bottom=12mm,outer=20mm,inner=13mm,foot=0mm]{geometry}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @marquinho!!! It works!!! I was also playing with ```\fancyfoot``` (and I was setting it as ```\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}```), but I forgot to check the settings of the ```geometry``` package....and you then came with the solution... Greattt!!! Many thanks!